# How to save an multidimensional array to database as separate rows in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(

[daterange] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14/02/2017 - 14/02/2017
        [1] => 14/02/2017 - 14/02/2017
    )

[location] => Array
    (
        [0] => dggfd
        [1] => hyd
    )

[latitude] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3545
        [1] => 111111
    )

[longitude] => Array
    (
        [0] => 43545
        [1] => 222222
    )

)
```

[image: mysql database image]

zeroth index as one row and 1 index as another row .

Comment: either in json encoded form or serialized form (I am telling based on your table structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support your array name is `$arr` then do this:

```
    $size = sizeof($arr['daterange']);
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) {
        $data = array(
            'daterange' => $arr['daterange'][$i],
            'location' => $arr['location'][$i],
            'latitude' => $arr['latitude'][$i],
            'longitude' => $arr['longitude'][$i],

        );
        $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
    }
```

Hope this will help you. Leave the comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: My Pleasure @saivamshi